# SOCKS5 proxy with username and password – ssh: could not resolve hostname, temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, socks5

I am quite new to SSH and Ubuntu. I am trying to connect to a server (e.g. `server1.com`) via SOCKS5 proxy host (e.g. `proxy1.com`) for which username and password is already given. I am including the jump host directives and path to proxy username and password in the SSH config file but no luck until now as I am always getting an error:

> unable to resolve proxy hostname

My `.ssh/config` file format is as below:

```
Host host1
HostName server1.com
Port 22
ProxyCommand ssh username:password@proxy.com portnum %h %p
```

And then I am using `ssh host1` to initiate the session.

Can anyone give me the possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh` does not accept the password in the format you are trying nor it can use the SOCKS proxy itself. The proxy command should use a `ncat`:

```
ProxyCommand ncat --proxy socks4host --proxy-type socks4 --proxy-auth username:password proxy.com portnum
```

or similar.

Comment: I used nc command. I am getting broken pipe error now. Is it possible to use socks5 with ncat?

Comment: Yes. Just have a look into the manual page to find out possible options.

Comment: `nc` -P proxy_username  not support socks5 yet.  only supported http connect. @Mani

Answer (score 0):

I've had some issues with the `ncat` command - looks like it implements the SOCKS5 protocol incorrectly and doesn't read part of the proxy server response, which then slips into ssh data and breaks ssh connection. I've used Ubuntu package `connect-proxy` instead.

```
$ sudo apt-get install connect-proxy
$ SOCKS5_PASSWD=proxypassword ssh -o "ProxyCommand=connect-proxy -5 -S proxyusername@proxy1.com %h %p" server1.com
```

Comment: seems `connect-proxy` not support specify password in cli

Comment: have to pass it use `env` cmd:
`ssh -o ProxyCommand='env SOCKS5_PASSWORD=proxy_pass connect-proxy -5 -S proxy_user@proxy_host %h %p'`

Comment: it's worked, but ungly. if some cmd work like `http_proxy=socks5://user:pass@host:port curl` it will be nice.